# hyperlink php returned db values

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to add hyperlink to my php code I tried many combination but couldn't figured out where I am getting wrong.

my query

```
echo "https://www.mywebsite.com" . $row["Page"] ."<br>";
```

I tried

```
echo '<a href=""https://www.mywebsite.com" . $row["Page"] ." </a>' <br>";
```

It doesn't work. Links come from db without hyperlink

Comment: So what is the final outcome of those attempt? Why do you claim it is "not a hyperlink"?

Comment: `echo '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/' . $row["Page"] .'">Link Title</a>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are wrong, the correct one is:

```
$row["Page"] = "/pages/women's-health.html";
$output = str_replace('\'', '', $row["Page"]);
echo "<a href='https://www.mywebsite.com".$output."'>".$row["Page"]."</a>";
```

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/958cc5ca03749572f159323228bd5ed498f0781f)**

Comment: Why would using single instead of double quotation make a difference?

Comment: And thats not a hyperlink!

Comment: @GeorgeK No there is no difference, but updated with double.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, the hyperlink was there but invisible because it wasn't wrapped around anything.

Comment: thanks pedram I have 2 questions
1) db fields has " ' " apostrophe but the code you send doesn't get text fully from db it cuts till " ' " how can I include all data 
 2) how can I change "Text"  as link by itself ?

Comment: @danone and you want to include `" ' " ` to your url? give me an example of db output

Comment: There is record in db "/pages/women's-health.html" your code only take "women" not full url as a result I can see only "https://www.mywebsite.com/women" not "https://www.mywebsite.com/Pages/Women's-Health.html"
I resolved question 2 but 1 still remain unresolved.

Comment: @danone in your case, you should replace `'` by nothing, because you can't include it in url. check out answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/'".$row['Page']."'>click</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
echo "<a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/".$row["Page"]."'>Link Name</a>";
```

You can remove the trailing `/` if your `$row["Page"]` has one.